# Refactoring C to C++ for Bernoulli Number calculation

Tags: c++, c, math, refactoring

Rosettacode has an [article](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers#C) for the calculation of [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Unfortunately it does not provide an example in C++, only one in C (as of December 27, 2016).

I am not familiar with C, but a lot of it is recognizable. How could this program be adapted for C++?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

#define mpq_for(buf, op, n)\
    do {\
        size_t i;\
        for (i = 0; i < (n); ++i)\
            mpq_##op(buf[i]);\
    } while (0)

void bernoulli(mpq_t rop, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int m, j;
    mpq_t *a = malloc(sizeof(mpq_t) * (n + 1));
    mpq_for(a, init, n + 1);

    for (m = 0; m <= n; ++m) {
        mpq_set_ui(a[m], 1, m + 1);
        for (j = m; j > 0; --j) {
            mpq_sub(a[j-1], a[j], a[j-1]);
            mpq_set_ui(rop, j, 1);
            mpq_mul(a[j-1], a[j-1], rop);
        }
    }

    mpq_set(rop, a[0]);
    mpq_for(a, clear, n + 1);
    free(a);
}

int main(void)
{
    mpq_t rop;
    mpz_t n, d;
    mpq_init(rop);
    mpz_inits(n, d, NULL);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 60; ++i) {
        bernoulli(rop, i);
        if (mpq_cmp_ui(rop, 0, 1)) {
            mpq_get_num(n, rop);
            mpq_get_den(d, rop);
            gmp_printf("B(%-2u) = %44Zd / %Zd\n", i, n, d);
        }
    }

    mpz_clears(n, d, NULL);
    mpq_clear(rop);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks! Even general recommendations are helpful!

Comment: Does GMP have a C++ version?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams From a quick search, I was unable to find if it did. From what I could find, they only had a select few algorithms (not one for Bernoulli numbers), but I may be wrong here. https://gmplib.org/manual/Other-Algorithms.html#Other-Algorithms

Comment: So if they don't have a specific C++ version then why do you think the code needs to be ported?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would like to use Bernoulli numbers in a C++ program.

Comment: The code you post is not complete, e.g. where is `mpq_t` defined.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: ... In `gmp.h`...

Comment: @Anonymous: ... What do you think this porting should look like?

Comment: Without knowing how gmp does it, it's a fair bet the code would compile as C++.    The only needed change would be casting the return from `malloc()`.    If you want an idiomatic C++ version, then more work would be required (using a standard container, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work on C++ without changing almost anything I guess, anyway there are a few things you could change:

- `malloc` for `new`: `mpg_t * a = new mpg_t[n+1];`

  or: `mpq_t * a = (mpq_t *) malloc(sizeof(mpq_t) * (n + 1));`
- `NULL` for `nullptr`
- Most C libraries have been renamed (and deprecated) from: `something.h` to `csomething`
  `#include <stdlib.h>` is now `#include <cstdlib>`
- You could write (included in `cstdint` header):

  `for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= 60; ++i) { /* ... */ }`

  instead of:

  `unsigned int i;`

  `for (i = 0; i <= 60; ++i) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: On systems where the type is available (in practice all), `<cstdint>` is only guaranteed to make `std::uint32_t` available. In order to have that name in the global namespace, as just `uint32_t`, include `<stdint.h>`. In C++ that's not a C header: it's defined in terms of `<cstdint>`, which in turn is defined in terms of the C header.

Comment: Also, re “It would work on C++ without changing anything I guess”, the code would not compile as C++ without casting the result from `malloc`.

Comment: Yep, that's true:

Answer (score 0):

Basically any C code will run on C++

For minimum refraction to OOB, just create a class called bernoully (for example) which will contain the bernoulli function and the macro,

That's it!